# Aggregate field in Tableau tool

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to receive your help in order to create an aggregate field in the Tableau tool.

I have a data source. The data source contains a few records (tuples/lines), and each record contains some attributes. I.e. a numeric value, a unique attribute (Key) and string.

For example, the first two rows share the same key (ID=A). This entity contains 2 records, the numeric value for each record is different (1 and 5).

I would like to create a new field. This new field should contain the minimum numeric value for each unique ID (entry).

In order to create this new field, I created a calculated field. The field’s formula is- **min(NumericField)**.
The problem occurred when I was trying to use this calculated aggregated field aggregate in order to create chats.  In this case, the aggregation is no longer performed on my key field.

For example, I would like to calculate the average for each category (The avg should be calculated for the aggregated new field)

Do you have any idea in order to resolve the mentioned problem?

Thank you! ☺️

[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIVfG.png)

Comment: Are you trying to bring in the ID column in the view or trying this without the ID column? I mean in your chart view you need to have both columns ID and newly calculated field. Can you please post how this appears in you tableau screen??

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I updated the description and updated the example picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LOD as below:

```
{fixed [id]: avg([newcalculatedfield])}
```

Let me know if you need more help. thanks!

Comment: Welcome @AlonKrichmar Nice to know it was helpful for you. Happy learning!